# Can i somehow avoid giving a subscript a real file?

Tags: python, perl, file

I have to calculate a lot of stuff for a huge proteome file, were i have ~ 30000 preteins in the dataset. 
I have a script where there are a lot of sub scripts which requires a single protein file

In perl:

```
my output = `somescript -do_something -with_this_single_protein_file`
```

I would like to ask, is there any way to avoid splitting the dataset into 30000 files each containing a single protein? Maybe in Python is there a way to give a Popen a stringIO, a file handler or something?

Thanks, Gábor

Comment: If `somescript` doesn't accept `-` as a file name to read standard input, does it accept `/dev/stdin`?

Comment: That's not valid Perl.  Maybe `my $output = ...;`?

Comment: Do you really have a separate subscript for each protein?

Comment: It will be more efficient to use one Perl script to call the subscripts, and to use `require` to pull them in instead of invoking them through `exec` or a shell, which is what the backticks do.  You will be invoking the Perl compiler once instead of 30000 times.

Comment: The thing i did was to make 30000 files, each containing one protein, make a list of their names, and iterate over them, so i can call
    `my $output =\`somescript -do_something n_th_protein\``;
And i would like to avoid makeing 30000 files

Comment: @reinerpost provided that `somescript` is also Perl code, of course.

Comment: @reinierpost: You realise that `require` invokes the compiler at run time? There is no way to run a Perl script without compiling it.

Comment: @Borodin: Hmm, yes, [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) really compiles and executes the script. So I'll correct what I wrote (ignore the above):

Comment: It will be more efficient to use one Perl script to call the subscripts, and to use require to pull them in instead of invoking them through exec or a shell, which is what the backticks do. You will be running everything in a single Perl process instead of forking 2*30000 subprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash's [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) to automatically create the temporary files you need.

```
while(<DATASET>) {
   my $output = system("/bin/bash", "-c", "somescript -do_something -with_this_single_protein_file <(echo \"$_\")");
}
```

Comment: Then why use Perl for the wrapper script at all?  `while read -r protein; do somescript -do_something -with_this_single_protein_file <(echo "$protein"); done <dataset`

Comment: @triplee That's better. I was assuming this was supposed to be part of a larger script.